# File pattern '*.psd' (from 'bundled' plugin) was reassigned to file type 'Adobe Photoshop' by 'Android' plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, file, android-gradle-plugin, archive

Got this message in event log:
Same like [File pattern '*.apk' (from 'bundled' plugin) was reassigned to file type 'APK' by 'Android' plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71186787/2173890)

In my project there is no ".psd" file.

What is that I must do?
Following is the full message:

```
File pattern '*.psd' (from 'bundled' plugin) was reassigned to file type 'Adobe Photoshop' by 'Android' plugin
You can confirm or revert reassigning pattern '*.psd'

Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'Adobe Photoshop'
Revert this pattern to file type 'Image'
Edit file type 'Image'
```

the last three lines are links.

Answer (score 1):

**select**
"Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'Adobe Photoshop'"
**for why**
see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71916617/2173890

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should just choose the first link for that we usually don't use .psd as a conventional image. And you can change the link type whenever you like after you doing that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).