# File pattern was reassigned to file type by 'Android' plugin. You can confirm or revert reassigning pattern

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I am developing an app using **Flutter 2.10.3** but I assume this issue is not related to Flutter. Since upgrading to **Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2** I am getting couple of messages in event log of Android Studio. PFA:

[image]

Does these messages have to do with any update? Should I just ignore them? Will there be any kind of impact on code or build if I just click on **Confirm** or **Reject**

Comment: Did you find an answer? This question is also unanswered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186787/file-pattern-apk-from-bundled-plugin-was-reassigned-to-file-type-apk-b

Comment: I ended up reverting both. Both web and Android devices are building still. Not sure if this will negatively effect production release, but I will find out when the time comes.

Comment: please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71916617/2173890

Answer (score 0):

**select**
"Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'APK'"
and
"Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'Adobe Photoshop'"
**for why**
see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71916617/2173890